# manage pointer to socket files descriptor

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, udp

I was wondering if it's possible manage pointer to socket udp file descriptor cause I have to sending data with send() to 2 different socket simultaneously.

I have a function that creates 2 sockets (socket() setsocket() bind() connect()... )
and another one that changes the socket (if one condition is true , but I dind't write this part)

```
  void set_socket(){                                    
    socket00 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    socket01 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    ...
    setsocket();
    setsocket();
    ....
    ....
  }


  int change_socketfd (int fd) {    
    if (fd == socket01 ) {          
        return ( socket00 );
    }
    else if (fd == socket00 ) {
        return ( socket01 );
    }
  }
```

Can I have a pointer like this?

```
    int *psock;
    psock=&change_socketfd(socket00);
    ris = send(*psock, datagram, sizeof(*datagram)+1 , 0);
```

What I need is to change dynamically the socketfd , but my code gives segmentation fault so I'm not sure if this method is correct or possible .
Thanks for the suggests

Answer (score 1):

The way you've done it will not work, because `&change_socketfd(socket00)` is giving it the address of a return value, which only exists temporarily. I don't see why this wouldn't do what you want:

```
int psock;
psock = change_socketfd(socket00);
ris = send(psock, datagram, sizeof(*datagram)+1 , 0);
```

If you really need it to be a pointer, though, then try this:

```
int *psock = malloc(sizeof(int*));
*psock = change_socketfd(socket00);
ris = send(*psock, datagram, sizeof(*datagram)+1 , 0);

...
//When you're finished with psock
free(psock);
```

Comment: isn't this code c++? I have never seen "int *psock = new int;" this type of declaration in ansi c